# In C# can I change a IValueConverter for 2 values and a NULL?

Tags: c#, binding, nullable, ivalueconverter

At present I have 2 radio buttons on my form for Male and Female. These are bound to my database where IsMale is either a 1 for male or 0 for female.

I then use a NegativeBooleanConverter to switch between the two. My xaml looks like this:

```
 <RadioButton Content="Male" Name="rbMale" IsChecked="{Binding Person.IsMale, Mode=TwoWay}" />
 <RadioButton Content="Female" Name="rbFelmale" IsChecked="{Binding Person.IsMale, Converter={StaticResource NegativeBooleanConverter}}" />
```

My NegativeBooleanConverter looks like this:

```
 public class NegativeBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
}
```

This all works great no problems!!

I have now uploaded more data into the database where IsMale is NULL as in it it unknown at the moment.

My question is is it possible to change the converter so that if the value is NULL neither radio button is selected???? If not what is the best way to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the `Convert` function you're looking to put in `NegativeBooleanConverter`: (also a similar `ConvertBack` function)

```
var b = value as bool?;
if (b.HasValue)
    return !b.Value;
else
    return false;
```

If `false` is too specific, you could have the parameter be the "default" value, which would be returned instead.

If the `IsChecked` on the Male button being null is causing a problem, you could make another converter that would `return ((bool?)value).GetValueOrDefault();`.

`ConvertBack` might be an issue, since you're essentially consolidating "male" and "unknown" into "not checked".  As long as it's not too overzealous in calling that and saving the state back to `IsMale`, you should be ok.